# When I assign shape keys to text, the objects lose their material

Tags: materials, shaders, shape-keys, text-object

I have created two text objects with the word ORIGIN in two different fonts. I can get the text to morph from one font to the other but after converting the text to curves and applying the shape keys the final text object loses it's material. How do I keep the material I applied to the text previously or do I need to add a new material to the curve object after conversion?

Also the original text before morphing with shape keys is using a mix shader with two emission shaders and texture coordinates linked to an empty to create a gradient wipe effect to change the text from black to white during animation.

Comment: Add a screenshot.